# Python lowercase error: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert all the values in a list to lowercase, using the following script:

```py
def Data_Cleanse(Data_IMP):
    # Import Data_IMP file
    # Drop the EventTime, and EventID columns

    Data_Cleanse = Data_IMP.drop(columns = ["eventId","eventTime"])

    res = [sub.replace('.', ' - ') for sub in Data_Cleanse]
    res = [sub.replace("organization", "organisation") for sub in res]

    for i in res:
        res = res.str.lower[i]

    Data_Cleanse.columns = res

    return Data_Cleanse
```

The script works well until it gets to the for loop. When it gets to that point, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

The a sample of the res output file looks like this:

> ['addrDate', 'birthCountry', 'birthDate', 'birthplace', 'branch',
>   'brokerCode', 'businessEmail', 'businessPhoneNumber']

Any suggestions on how to get around this error?

Comment: Because it doesn't have a `.str` attribute. It seems like you've found code for Pandas Series objects and are trying to apply to lists. That won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original error is likely because you're trying to run code on a list that is meant to be run on a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object. You can actually simplify your script quite a bit by chaining some of these string operations in a single list comprehension. Something like:

```
res = [sub.replace('.', ' - ').replace("organization", "organisation").lower() for sub in Data_Cleanse]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is incorrect, that's not how lists work in Python:

```
for i in res:
    res = res.str.lower[i]
```

I believe you meant to do this:

```
for i in range(len(res)):
    res[i] = res[i].lower()
```

Or even better, this - using list comprehensions:

```
res = [s.lower() for s in res]
```